# Problems with passing the correct Realm object from tableview for index section and row

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm having issues with segue to next view controller. I have a tableview displaying realm data in rows and sections. 
If I press the add button its goes to view controller and allows me to tha data and stores it all correctly.
If I select the cell it should take me to the same view controller and fill the text fields with correct data.

At the moment I can only select the data for the first section indexpath rows. Every cell I select from other sections still only displays the data from the first section.

I have tried numerous ways to get the correct section but failed.

Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using xcode 7.3 and realm 2.0.3.

Below is the code in my tableview.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let items = try! Realm().objects(ContactItem).sorted(["Initial", "Name"])

var sectionNames: [String] {
    return Set(items.valueForKeyPath("Initial") as! [String]).sort()
}

//var sectionTitles = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func setupUI() {
    tableView.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func items(forSection section: Int) -> Results<ContactItem> {
    return items.filter("Initial == %@", sectionNames[section])
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionNames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionNames[section]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items(forSection: section).count
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return sectionNames as [String]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = items.filter("Initial == %@", sectionNames[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row].Name
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let contact : ContactItem = items[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("editContact", sender: contact)
    print("Selected row at \(indexPath.row)")
    print("Selected section at \(indexPath.section)")
}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
 {
 if(segue.identifier == "editContact")
    {
    let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddEntryViewController
    viewController.contact = sender as! ContactItem
    }

 }

@IBAction func addContact(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

}

EDIT both answers below thank you.

One more quick question - currently it only displays the index section titles when a contact has been added but i would like all the index titles displayed down the right from the start wether they have a contact or not. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
let contact : ContactItem = items[indexPath.row]
```

It should be getting the item and filtering them. You have a method of doing that already, so `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should use that too.

```
let contact : ContactItem = items(forSection: indexPath.section)[indexPath.row]
```

You should probably use that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so you don't have the same filtering logic in two different places.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I could of sworn I'd tried that before but maybe I didn't type it correct. I think I tried so many different ways that I just ended up confused.

Comment: One more quick question - currently it only displays the index section titles when a contact has been added but i would like all the index titles displayed down the right from the start wether they have a contact or not. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with this one.

```html
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

let contact: ContactItem = items.filter("Initial == %@", sectionNames[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row]
performSegueWithIdentifier("editContact", sender: contact)
print("Selected row at \(indexPath.row)")
print("Selected section at \(indexPath.section)")
}
```

Comment: Cheers that works as well. Any ideas with my second question?

Comment: That's really great to hear. Please vote me if that code worked.
Where is your second questions? I don't see any other question at the top.

Comment: It's in the comments of the first answer.

Comment: Yes, Its possible to add section header at the right like Contact in you iPhone.

Comment: I can get them to display on the right but then I can't get them linked to go to the correct section with my code.